# Snipcart Return JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, snipcart

Any guidance or an example of exactly what I need to do to return the information below would be great.
I'm using js, jquery & HTML

1. I need to add this: Content-Type header is application/json
2. When the request comes I need to reply with the Json below

https://docs.snipcart.com/configuration/json-crawler#validating-the-request

> When Snipcart makes the request to the URL, if your response
>   Content-Type header is application/json, we'll use our JSON validator
>   instead of the HTML one.
>
> You must return us a JSON having the following properties.

```
{
  "id": "20",
  "price": 50.00,
  "url": "https://snipcart.com/products/1.json"
}
```

Comment: look in to Ajax. There are numerous tutorials. And jQuery handles the details of it very well.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this in PHP and getting the values using the URL.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $myID = $_REQUEST['scene'];
    $myPrice = $_REQUEST['price'];

    $data = [
      "id" => $myID,
      "price" => $myPrice,
      "url" => "https://yoursite.com/shop/test/snipcart.php" 
    ];
    echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```